# Http call behind proxy work in RestSharp but not in HttpClient

Tags: c#, http, httpclient, restsharp

I have a server behind proxy and i need to make http call to exteranl api
I can make this work with RestSharp but not in `HttpClient`.

RestSharp code working on local machine and server:

```cs
var clientrr = new RestClient($"{googleVerificationUrl}?secret={_captchaSettings.ServerKey}&response={captchaToken}");
var req = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
clientrr.Proxy = new WebProxy($"http://proxyAddress:8080");
req.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
req.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };
IRestResponse response = clientrr.Execute(req);
```

`HttpClient` work on local machin but not in server:

```cs
var proxy = new WebProxy
{
    Address = new Uri($"http://proxyAddress:8080"),
    UseDefaultCredentials = true,
};
var httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler
{
    Proxy = proxy,
};
var client = new HttpClient(handler: httpClientHandler, disposeHandler: true);
var response = await client.PostAsync($"{googleVerificationUrl}?secret={_captchaSettings.ServerKey}&response={captchaToken}", null);
var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I got an exception without too much info.

On my local machine its working under IIS Express with Visual Studio, on the server its working under IIS, both my local machin and the server are behind the same proxy.

How to make this work with `HttpClient`?